# Getting no such column in the table

Tags: android, sqlite

get an exception no such column but actually column data is present in the database am unable to catch that exception can any one help me

```
07-13 09:17:41.720: E/SQLiteLog(16717): (1) near "Yongming": syntax error
07-13 09:17:41.720: D/AndroidRuntime(16717): Shutting down VM
07-13 09:17:41.730: W/dalvikvm(16717): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-13 09:17:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(16717): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 09:17:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(16717): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Yongming": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM Exhibitors_Bookmark_table WHERE Exhibitor_data=Shanghai Yongming Electronics Co.,LTD.
07-13 09:17:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(16717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
07-13 09:17:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(16717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
07-13 09:17:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(16717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
07-13 09:17:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(16717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
07-13 09:17:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(16717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
07-13 09:17:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(16717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
07-13 09:17:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(16717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1491)
07-13 09:17:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(16717):    at datahandler.FavoratesDB.delete_exhibitor_name(FavoratesDB.java:156)
```

Comment: [See reference link here](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in sqlite for where clause you need to use apostrophe around the search string. So your query should look like

```
DELETE FROM Exhibitors_Bookmark_table WHERE Exhibitor_data='Shanghai Yongming Electronics Co.,LTD.'
```

may be this is the reason of not getting.